# Rewriterule not applied in Apache 2.4 httpd.conf

Tags: mod-rewrite, httpd.conf, apache2.4

I would like to redirect via a RewriteRule (mod_rewrite) enabled in httpd.conf my URL:

https://mysite.domain.tld/index_php_file.php?ab=**ident_keys**&ac=5GU7VBNAH45DA5

TO:

https://mysite.domain.tld/index_php_file.php?ab=**ident_key_1024**&ac=5GU7VBNAH45DA5

I have tried it with a number of rules without luck:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} hmysite.domain.tld
RewriteRule ^/index_php_file\.php\?ab=ident_keys&ac=$ https://hmysite.domain.tld/index_php_file.php?ab=ident_key_1024&ac= [R=301,L,QSA]
```

nor

```
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^ac=(.*)$
RewriteRule ^/?([a-z-0-9-_.]+)$ /$1/index_php_file.php?ab=ident_key_1024&ac=%1 [L,R=301]
```

seems to rewrite the URL.

Any suggestions on what I'm missing?

Thank you very much.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the solution, it may help someone.

```
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ac=([A-Z0-9]+)
RewriteRule ^/?([-a-zA-Z0-9_+]+)$ index_php_file.php?ab=ident_key_1024&ac=$1 [R=301,L]
```

It is enough to look for the string (containing UPPERCASE chars and numbers only) with the `RewriteCond` and rewrite the URL `RewriteRule` to the desired format and append the value of the variable from the query.

Do not forget to enable the `mod_rewrite` module within Apache. To take effect a restart is also necessary of course.